# Unity bloom effect not working (cinemachine, URP)

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp, cinemachine

I've been working on a fairly large project in Unity. Until recently, we weren't using universal render pipeline (URP) and made that change. When we did, all the bloom effect we already had in place to create a neon glow look for our game disappeared, and everything looks opaque. All the tutorials I found say that it's fairly simple to add this effect, but I can't make it work. I'm starting to get suspicious of the Cinemachine in the main camera, since it's brought us problems in the past. I'll just state some of the things I've tried:

- The post processing checkbox is ticked in the camera view.
- My materials have emission turned on with colors that used to work before URP.
- The camera has the volume component, with an override of bloom and the values of intensity and threshold super high.
- I've also dropped a global Volume in the scene with a volume component with bloom effect (one solution suggested I do that)

I think that's everything. Please let me know of any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried making a branch and removing Cinemachine?